# Correct way to type incoming requests with Typescript and Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, types, zod

I'm validating incoming requests with zod and also generating my types for the body etc etc with the infer functionality.

Now my question is, how to best specify these types in my Express controller?

Let's say my endpoint needs this body structure:

```
{
  "name": string,
  "address": string
}
```

I have created a type from my zod schema, let's call it UserRequestBody.
Now I would obviously like to use this type to type the incoming request in the controller.
I've made it work by using the interface `RequestHandler` from Express, like this:

```
const newUser: RequestHandler<unknown, unknown, UserRequestBody, unknown> = async (req, res, next) => {
  // here, I can now access the properties directly from the req.body
  console.log(req.body.name)
}
```

That's nice with the intellisense and all, but I'm wondering if this is the way to do it?
Wondering how other people would approach this. Is there some other, smarter way, of typing the request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [zod-express-middleware](https://github.com/Aquila169/zod-express-middleware) package.

> Middleware for `express` that uses `zod` to make requests type-safe.

It seems you only provided the `UserRequestBody` type to pass the TSC type check. But there is no validation.

E.g.

```
import express from 'express';
import { validateRequest } from 'zod-express-middleware';
import { z } from 'zod';

const app = express();

// app is an express app
app.get(
  '/',
  validateRequest({
    body: z.object({
      name: z.string(),
      address: z.string(),
    }),
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    // req.body is now strictly-typed and confirms to the zod schema above.
    // req.body has type { name: string; address: string; };
    return res.json({ message: 'Validation for body passed' });
  },
);
```

`package.json`:

```json
"zod": "^3.21.4",
"zod-express-middleware": "^1.4.0",
"@types/express": "^4.17.17",
"express": "^4.18.2",
```